Azure Pipeline task for Veracode scan for Ionic Capacitor project. Build artifact file path is not valid
I am trying veracode for first time. I wanted to scan my ionic project through azure pipeline.
Below is my project structure:

so I have added a task in azure-pipeline.yml file.
# Starter pipeline
# Start with a minimal pipeline that you can customize to build and deploy your code.
# Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:
# https://aka.ms/yaml

trigger:
- develop

pool:
  vmImage: macOS-latest

steps:

- script: npm install
  displayName: 'Install dependencies'
  workingDirectory: $(pluginDir)
  
- script: |
    # Add any necessary setup steps for running iOS tests (e.g., installing dependencies, setting up simulators)
    brew install cocoapods
    cd $(pluginDir)/ios
    pod install
  displayName: 'Setup for iOS tests'
  
- task: JavaToolInstaller@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '17'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    jdkSourceOption: 'PreInstalled'
  
- task: Gradle@3
  inputs:
    gradleWrapperFile: '$(pluginDir)/android/gradlew'
    workingDirectory: '$(pluginDir)/android'
    tasks: 'test'
    publishJUnitResults: false
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    sonarQubeRunAnalysis: false
    spotBugsAnalysis: false

- task: Xcode@5
  inputs:
    actions: 'test'
    configuration: 'Debug'
    sdk: 'iphonesimulator'
    xcWorkspacePath: '$(pluginDir)/ios/Plugin.xcworkspace'
    scheme: 'PluginTests'
    packageApp: false
    destinationPlatformOption: 'iOS'
    destinationSimulators: 'iPhone 14'

- task: Veracode@3
  displayName: 'Upload dist to Veracode'
  inputs:
    ConnectionDetailsSelection: 'Service Connection'
    AnalysisService: 'Vera***'
    veracodeAppProfile: 'K2 Mobile Component Media'
    version: '$(Build.BuildNumber)'
    filepath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/$(pluginDir)/dist'
    maximumWaitTime: '360'
  condition: ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest')


- task: Npm@1
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    workingDir: '$(pluginDir)'
    publishRegistry: 'useFeed'
    publishFeed: '694ea4fc-*************'

- task: UniversalPackages@0
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/$(docsDir)'
    feedsToUsePublish: 'internal'
    vstsFeedPublish: '694ea4fc-*************'
    vstsFeedPackagePublish: '$(docsDir)'
    versionOption: 'patch'

I am getting below response
Accessing Service Connection
Getting Service Connection URL
Getting Auth Service Connection
Auth Scheme :Token
filepath: /Users/runner/work/1/s/k2-mobile-component-media-plugin/dist
veracodeAppProfile: K2 Mobile Component Media
createProfile: false
failBuildIfUploadAndScanBuildStepFails: false
failBuildOnPolicyFail: false
importResults: false
version: 20240806.4
sandboxName: undefined
createSandBox: false
MaximumWaitTime: 360
Autoscan: true
isDebugEnabled: false
Autoscan: true
/Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Java_Temurin-Hotspot_jdk/17.0.12-7/x64/Contents/Home/bin/java -version
openjdk version "17.0.12" 2024-07-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17.0.12+7 (build 17.0.12+7)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-17.0.12+7 (build 17.0.12+7, mixed mode)
Veracode upload & scan task started
Build artifact file path is not valid
Ensure the path to the application artifact or to the folder that contains artifacts for upload is valid.
Finishing: Upload dist to Veracode

Is there a specific folder to add it in filepath to scan? Or shall I zip everything and send it to scan whole project. How to fix this?

According to packaging requirements, for the Ionic project, you should

Zip the application source files and upload the ZIP file.

You can add a ArchiveFiles@2 task to zip your source files before Veracode@3 task.
- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '{The folder of your source files}'
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: true
- task: Veracode@3
  displayName: 'Upload dist to Veracode'
  inputs:
    ConnectionDetailsSelection: 'Service Connection'
    AnalysisService: 'Vera***'
    veracodeAppProfile: 'K2 Mobile Component Media'
    version: '$(Build.BuildNumber)'
    filepath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    maximumWaitTime: '360'
  condition: ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest')

See more info from Package your code.
